# How to get all the cities or localities from the given country in iOS?

Tags: ios

As we know, we can get all the country codes and their display names through:

```
NSArray *countryArray = [NSLocale ISOCountryCodes];
for (NSString *countryCode in countryArray)
{
    NSString *displayNameString = [locale displayNameForKey:NSLocaleCountryCode value:countryCode];
}
```

However, I want to know all the cities or localities from the given country, Do any guys know? Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10703978/how-to-get-all-the-cities-for-a-country-in-iphone-app

Comment: you can use Google location API.